# Java: separar linha em colunas por posição de caracteres

Tags: java, regex, split

Olá, virei a internet de cabeça pra baixo tentando resolver esse problema.

Tenho um texto que nesse formato:

```
012016010402AAPL34      010APPLE       DRN          R$  000000000415000000000042200000000004150000000000421300000000042080000000003950000000000435000005000000000000012500000000000052664400000000000000009999123100000010000000000000BRAAPLBDR004115
```

Isso é uma única linha em que preciso separar as colunas pela posição do caracter, por exemplo:

- coluna 1: até o segundo caracter;
- coluna 2: até o terceiro caracter;
- coluna 3: até o décimo caracter;
- E assim por diante.

Essa foi a expressão em Regex que encontrei para dividir em duas partes, porém não consegui encontrar uma maneira inteligente de fazer isso sequencialmente.

```
String[] linhaArray = linha.split("(?<=\\G^.{2})");
```

Eu quero mesmo é separar essas colunas usando um delimitador " ; ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não use regex. Se quer pegar posições específicas da string, use `substring`. Ex:

```
String linha = "012016010402AAPL34      010APPLE       DRN          R$  000000000415000000000042200000000004150000000000421300000000042080000000003950000000000435000005000000000000012500000000000052664400000000000000009999123100000010000000000000BRAAPLBDR004115";

// coloque aqui todas as posições das colunas 
int posicoes[] = { 2, 3, 10 };
int inicio = 0;
for (int pos: posicoes) {
    System.out.println(linha.substring(inicio, pos));
    inicio = pos;
}
```

No exemplo acima eu só peguei 3 colunas: a primeira é do início da string até a posição 1 (pois o índice final não é incluso), ou seja, pega os 2 primeiros caracteres.

A segunda coluna pega o terceiro caractere (pois vai da posição 2 - já que a primeira posição é zero - até a 3, mas como a posição final não é inclusa, ele pega apenas o terceiro caractere).

A terceira coluna pega até o décimo caractere, e para pegar mais colunas, basta adicionar as posições no array `posicoes`.

---

Se a ideia é ter um array com as colunas:

```
int posicoes[] = { 2, 3, 10 };
String linhaArray[] = new String[3];
int inicio = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < posicoes.length; i++) {
    int pos = posicoes[i];
    if (pos > linha.length) break;
    linhaArray[i] = linha.substring(inicio, pos);
    inicio = pos;
}
```

Incluí uma verificação para interromper o loop caso a posição seja maior que o tamanho da string, pois a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) diz que neste caso é lançada uma exceção.

---

Mas se quiser muito usar regex:

```
String linha = "012016010402AAPL34      010APPLE       DRN          R$  000000000415000000000042200000000004150000000000421300000000042080000000003950000000000435000005000000000000012500000000000052664400000000000000009999123100000010000000000000BRAAPLBDR004115";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^(.{2})(.)(.{7})").matcher(linha);                                     
if (matcher.find()) {
    String linhaArray[] = new String [matcher.groupCount()];
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        linhaArray[i - 1] = matcher.group(i);
    }
}
```

A ideia é ter vários [grupos de captura, usando pares de parênteses](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Dentro deles eu coloco o ponto ([que corresponde a qualquer caractere](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)), junto com a [quantidade](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (por exemplo, `{2}` para indicar que quero 2 caracteres - a exceção é quando a quantidade é 1, aí não precisa quantificar).

Depois basta ver quantos grupos têm, criar o array e ir adicionando o valor de cada grupo nele.

Mas eu ainda acho a primeira solução mais simples.

Comment: Obrigado hkotsubo, funcionou!

Comment: @LuizFelipeBorges Adicionei uma solução com regex, mas foi apenas como "curiosidade", pois eu ainda acho que com `substring` é mais simples (e não testei, mas provavelmente também é mais eficiente que regex)